# How to change the version of a compilation unit?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I'm trying to analyze why a (quite large) program segfaults. If the program crashes it writes a core dump to /tmp which I try to analyze using gdb. However, gdb gives me the following error:

```
Reading symbols from /home/user/Executable...Dwarf Error: 
wrong version in compilation unit header (is 4, should be 2) 
[in module /home/user/Executable]
```

I've searched a bit and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671009/dwarf-error-wrong-version-in-compilation-unit-header-is-4-should-be-2) on stackoverflow where the author assumes that this was the result of compiling parts of the code (precisely a library he/she was using) with a different `-g` flag.

I've checked the version of the compilation unit on my executable (C++) and a library (C) I'm using in my program via

```
readelf --debug-dump=info Executable | grep -A 2 'Compilation Unit @'
```

And apparently the executable has everywhere a version of 4, while the library has a version of 2. I'm wondering if it is possible to fix this and how? I'm also quite curious how this problem actually rose in the first place (toying around with the debug level via the -g flag doesn't helped at all).

TIA

Comment: What is your OS, version of gcc, and version of gdb?

Comment: The OS is Debian 6.07 and gcc is in version 4.8 (I've had to compile it by myself since I'm using C++11 features). I'm using gdb version shipped with Debian (meaning that it is gdb 7.0.1).

Comment: Yes that's the reason. Always go with the latest version of gdb. (Please accept your own answer so that others would instantly see that it worked).

Comment: I really would like to accept my answer, but my "reptutation" is too low and so I have to wait 2 days before I can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of inputs that produce a single object file (.o) is called a compilation unit; for more info, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation_unit). For convenience, "compilation unit" is often abbreviated as "CU."

When compiling a CU with debug information, each CU has a debug information section that begins with a CU header; this header contains a version number.  This debugging information is in a format called [DWARF](http://dwarfstd.org).

Over time the DWARF standard has evolved. For each major release, the version number has changed. This ensures that when a DWARF producer (e.g., a compiler) creates debug information, the DWARF consumer (e.g., a debugger) knows what to expect.

When gdb complains about the version of a CU, it is really complaining about the version number that is in the DWARF CU header.

To avoid this problem, as you have discovered, you have to make sure that your entire software development toolchain (compiler, linker, debugger) is able to "speak" the same DWARF version. Your solution of compiling the latest version of gdb is correct.

Answer (score 5):

From the [GCC 4.8 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html):

> Before GCC 4.8 the default version used was DWARF2. To make GCC 4.8 generate an older DWARF version use -g together with -gdwarf-2 or -gdwarf-3

In my case, adding

```
-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf
```

made the old debugger to work again. I agree that using a newer GDB version is the best solution in most cases, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled the library with g++ (instead of gcc) which resulted in the desired compilation unit. However, this still resulted in the DWARF error thrown by gdb and so I compiled the latest version of gdb on the machine and finally it works now.